# Windows Update Fails and missing registry keys

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-update

I have windows 10 Home edition, 1607 version (14393.321 build) and lately my computer has been trying to update to 1703 version but fails. I've tried the usual stuff like troubleshooter, clean boot, system restore.

The error code is **0x8007001f**.

Then I tried to reset my computer, which failed so I saw a solution about running a sfc, which failed with the message: "windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation".

All these led me to the following post: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/windows-modules-installer-error126/2a45788d-c1e5-4b62-a5b1-2410cbcbf813?auth=1 and the first answer by "theholycow" (yes I know, it's from 2011 but bear with me)
which suggests that there is a registry key missing HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Version

This key indeed is missing from my computer, but when I navigate to C:\Windows\Servicing\Version to see what key needs to be added, I have 3 subfolders inside: 
[image]

The first two are empty, the third is not.

So first of all, what key do I have to add, if any? 
Second, will this fix my problem? Do I have to format my pc? Why does reset fail?

I tried adding the key with .349 at the end but sfc still fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing several 1607 updates.  That is likely part of your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound wouldn't troubleshooter fix that? or the "check for updates" option?

Comment: All I know is the current build of 1607 is 14393.1944 which means you are 14 months behind on updates.  You should determine the reason your system hasn’t updated in 14 months.

Comment: 14393.351 was the next build after 14393.321, 14393.349 wasn’t released to the stable channels (or was re-released as .351)

Answer (score 3):

After having updates *repeatedly* fail on a number of different PC's, I find it's easiest [to download the entire ISO for Windows 10, use the Windows Media Creation tool to create a USB boot drive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), and do an upgrade from it. It is far more reliable than the Windows Update *patch* process, and usually faster, too. Be sure to select *Keep personal files and apps*, though it's a very good idea to image the disk first, in case something goes wrong.

Regrettably, this doesn't determine what issue(s) caused the update failure, but I am not confident a Windows Vista issue prevents a Window 10 update, as you suggest.

Comment: I think if I can't determine the cause of the issue i will ultimately do this. Does this fix the cause of the update failure though (ie it updates aaand this update fixes the problem for future updates), or is it just a way around it? So i'll always have a problem with updates?

Comment: My experience has been that there may be multiple issues but upgrading from ISO fixes the issues so that later updates *usually* work. Still, after I've made changes to the OS (e.g.turning off telemetry), it may break updates again.

Comment: So I burned the iso on a dvd but booting from it only lets me clean install. The upgrade option prompts me to run the setup from inside windows, but this fails as before.